# SQL Server RMO - An error when creating a publication

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, rmo

I have the following situation: distribution as distributor database, production1 as publication database and production2 as a subscriber. When I'm trying to create a publication via C# RMO the following error occurs:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'pubid', table 'production1.dbo.IHpublications';  column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nCould not create the publication.\r\nChanged database context to 'production1'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

the code is attached below - taken form MSDN:

```
        // Set the Publisher, publication database, and publication names.
        string publicationName = "productionTran";
        string publicationDbName = "production1";
        string publisherName = "OSKAR-KOMPUTER";

        ReplicationDatabase publicationDb;
        TransPublication publication;

        // Create a connection to the Publisher using Windows Authentication.
        ServerConnection conn;
        conn = new ServerConnection(publisherName);


        try
        {
            // Connect to the Publisher.
            conn.Connect();

            // Enable the AdventureWorks database for transactional publishing.
            publicationDb = new ReplicationDatabase(publicationDbName, conn);

            // If the database exists and is not already enabled, 
            // enable it for transactional publishing.
            if (publicationDb.LoadProperties())
            {
                if (!publicationDb.EnabledTransPublishing)
                {
                    publicationDb.EnabledTransPublishing = true;
                }

                // If the Log Reader Agent does not exist, create it.
                if (!publicationDb.LogReaderAgentExists)
                {
                    // Specify the Windows account under which the agent job runs.
                    // This account will be used for the local connection to the 
                    // Distributor and all agent connections that use Windows Authentication.
                    //publicationDb.LogReaderAgentProcessSecurity.Login = winLogin;
                    //publicationDb.LogReaderAgentProcessSecurity.Password = winPassword;

                    // Explicitly set authentication mode for the Publisher connection
                    // to the default value of Windows Authentication.
                    publicationDb.LogReaderAgentPublisherSecurity.WindowsAuthentication = true;

                    // Create the Log Reader Agent job.
                    publicationDb.CreateLogReaderAgent();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                    "The {0} database does not exist at {1}.",
                    publicationDb, publisherName));
            }

            // Set the required properties for the transactional publication.
            publication = new TransPublication();
            publication.ConnectionContext = conn;
            publication.Name = publicationName;
            publication.DatabaseName = publicationDbName;

            // Specify a transactional publication (the default).
            publication.Type = PublicationType.Transactional;

            // Activate the publication so that we can add subscriptions.
            publication.Status = State.Active;

            // Enable push and pull subscriptions and independent Distribition Agents.
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.AllowPull;
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.AllowPush;
            publication.Attributes |= PublicationAttributes.IndependentAgent;

            // Specify the Windows account under which the Snapshot Agent job runs.
            // This account will be used for the local connection to the 
            // Distributor and all agent connections that use Windows Authentication.
           // publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentProcessSecurity.Login = winLogin;
          //  publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentProcessSecurity.Password = winPassword;

            // Explicitly set the security mode for the Publisher connection
            // Windows Authentication (the default).
            publication.SnapshotGenerationAgentPublisherSecurity.WindowsAuthentication = true;

            if (!publication.IsExistingObject)
            {
                // Create the transactional publication.
                publication.Create();

                // Create a Snapshot Agent job for the publication.
                publication.CreateSnapshotAgent();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                    "The {0} publication already exists.", publicationName));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Implement custom application error handling here.
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
                "The publication {0} could not be created.", publicationName), ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Disconnect();
        }
```

what I can tell more, distributor and publicator are installed. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the other interesting thing is, when I'm trying to add a publication via Management Studio - publication Wizard - the same error occurs.

Comment: also when I've changed the replication type to snapshot it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
Running the below on the database I wanted to publish is what worked for me.

```
DROP TABLE dbo.iharticles;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihcolumns;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihconstrainttypes;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihindextypes;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublications;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublishercolumnconstraints;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublishercolumnindexes;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublishercolumns;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublisherconstraints;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublisherindexes;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublishers;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihpublishertables;
DROP TABLE dbo.ihsubscriptions;
DROP TABLE dbo.syssubscriptions
DROP VIEW dbo.syspublications;
DROP VIEW dbo.sysarticlecolumns;
DROP VIEW dbo.syssubscriptions;
DROP VIEW dbo.sysextendedarticlesview;
DROP VIEW dbo.ihextendedarticleview;
DROP VIEW dbo.ihextendedsubscriptionview;
```

I then disabled publishing using the wizard and then re-enabled it using the wizard and was able to create the publications.